# ArangoDB: how to optimize FILTER on a subquery on big collections

Tags: graph-databases, arangodb

I have a fairly simple data model (inspired by IMDB data) to link films to their directors or actors.
This includes 3 collections:

- document collection `Titles`
- document collection `Persons`
- edge collection `core_edge_values_links` with an `attribute` field to determine the role of the person (director, actor...)

`Titles` are linked to `Persons` through a `core_edge_values_links` edge:

[image]

Now, I'm trying to find all Titles which have a link to any director.
Query is:

```
FOR r IN titles
    LET rlinkVal =  FIRST( 
        FOR rv, re IN 1 OUTBOUND r._id
            core_edge_values_links
            FILTER re.attribute == 'directors'
         RETURN re
     ) 
     FILTER rlinkVal != null
LIMIT 0, 20
RETURN r
```

This query will take about 2.5s (and up to almost 2 minutes with fullCount enable) on a DB with 1M titles, about 200k persons and about 4M edges. I have about 600k matching titles.

To try to speed this up, I added an index on the `core_edge_values_links` colllection on fields `_from` and `attribute`. Unfortunately, the traversal won't take advantage of this index.

I also tried to use a simple join instead of the traversal:

```
FOR r IN titles
    LET rlinkVal =  FIRST( 
        FOR e IN core_edge_values_links
            FILTER e._from == r._id AND e.attribute == 'directors'
            RETURN true
     ) 
     FILTER rlinkVal != null
     LIMIT 0, 20
     RETURN r
```

This time, the index is used, but query time is pretty much the same as with the traversal (about 2.5s, see profiling data below).

This makes me wondering if the problem just comes from the number of titles in the collection (about 1M) as they're all scanned in the initial FOR but I don't see how I could index it. This is a fairly simple use case, I don't feel this should take so long.
This is a fairly simple use case, I don't feel this should take so long.

Here is profiling data provided by arango.

**With the traversal:**

```
Query String (241 chars, cacheable: false):
 FOR r IN titles
     LET rlinkVal =  FIRST( 
         FOR rv, re IN 1 OUTBOUND r._id
             core_edge_values_links
             FILTER re.attribute == 'directors'
          RETURN re
      ) 
      FILTER rlinkVal != null
 LIMIT 0, 20
 RETURN r

Execution plan:
 Id   NodeType                  Calls    Items   Runtime [s]   Comment
  1   SingletonNode                 1        1       0.00001   * ROOT
  2   EnumerateCollectionNode     305   304000       0.08433     - FOR r IN titles   /* full collection scan  */
  4   CalculationNode             305   304000       0.07084       - LET #6 = r.`_id`   /* attribute expression */   /* collections used: r : titles */
 16   SubqueryStartNode           609   608000       0.12038       - LET #3 = ( /* subquery begin */
  5   TraversalNode               306   305000       1.93808         - FOR /* vertex optimized away */, re  /* edge */ IN 1..1  /* min..maxPathDepth */ OUTBOUND #6 /* startnode */  core_edge_values_links
  6   CalculationNode             306   305000       0.02857           - LET #10 = (re.`attribute` == "directors")   /* simple expression */
  7   FilterNode                  305   304000       0.05040           - FILTER #10
 15   LimitNode                   305   304000       0.00927           - LIMIT 0, 1
 17   SubqueryEndNode             304   303000       0.05520           - RETURN  re ) /* subquery end */
 10   CalculationNode             304   303000       0.02094       - LET rlinkVal = FIRST(#3)   /* simple expression */
 11   CalculationNode             304   303000       0.01909       - LET #12 = (rlinkVal != null)   /* simple expression */
 12   FilterNode                    1       20       0.01508       - FILTER #12
 13   LimitNode                     1       20       0.00001       - LIMIT 0, 20
 14   ReturnNode                    1       20       0.00001       - RETURN r

Indexes used:
 By   Name   Type   Collection               Unique   Sparse   Selectivity   Fields        Ranges
  5   edge   edge   core_edge_values_links   false    false        34.87 %   [ `_from` ]   base OUTBOUND

Traversals on graphs:
 Id  Depth  Vertex collections  Edge collections        Options                                  Filter / Prune Conditions             
 5   1..1                       core_edge_values_links  uniqueVertices: none, uniqueEdges: path  FILTER (re.`attribute` == "directors")

Optimization rules applied:
 Id   RuleName
  1   move-calculations-up
  2   optimize-subqueries
  3   optimize-traversals
  4   splice-subqueries

Query Statistics:
 Writes Exec   Writes Ign   Scan Full   Scan Index   Filtered   Peak Mem [b]   Exec Time [s]
           0            0      304000            0     302977        1605632         2.41360

Query Profile:
 Query Stage           Duration [s]
 initializing               0.00000
 parsing                    0.00006
 optimizing ast             0.00001
 loading collections        0.00001
 instantiating plan         0.00006
 optimizing plan            0.00120
 executing                  2.41225
 finalizing                 0.00003
```

**With the join:**

```
Query String (232 chars, cacheable: false):
 FOR r IN titles
     LET rlinkVal =  FIRST( 
         FOR e IN core_edge_values_links
             FILTER e._from == r._id AND e.attribute == 'directors'
             RETURN true
      ) 
      FILTER rlinkVal != null
 LIMIT 0, 20
 RETURN r

Execution plan:
 Id   NodeType                  Calls    Items   Runtime [s]   Comment
  1   SingletonNode                 1        1       0.00001   * ROOT
  7   CalculationNode               1        1       0.00000     - LET #7 = true   /* json expression */   /* const assignment */
  2   EnumerateCollectionNode     305   304000       0.09654     - FOR r IN titles   /* full collection scan  */
 17   SubqueryStartNode           609   608000       0.13655       - LET #2 = ( /* subquery begin */
 16   IndexNode                   305   304000       2.29080         - FOR e IN core_edge_values_links   /* persistent index scan, scan only */    
 15   LimitNode                   305   304000       0.00992           - LIMIT 0, 1
 18   SubqueryEndNode             304   303000       0.05765           - RETURN  #7 ) /* subquery end */
 10   CalculationNode             304   303000       0.02272       - LET rlinkVal = FIRST(#2)   /* simple expression */
 11   CalculationNode             304   303000       0.02060       - LET #9 = (rlinkVal != null)   /* simple expression */
 12   FilterNode                    1       20       0.01656       - FILTER #9
 13   LimitNode                     1       20       0.00000       - LIMIT 0, 20
 14   ReturnNode                    1       20       0.00000       - RETURN r

Indexes used:
 By   Name                      Type         Collection               Unique   Sparse   Selectivity   Fields                     Ranges
 16   idx_1742224911374483456   persistent   core_edge_values_links   false    false            n/a   [ `_from`, `attribute` ]   ((e.`_from` == r.`_id`) && (e.`attribute` == "directors"))

Optimization rules applied:
 Id   RuleName
  1   move-calculations-up
  2   optimize-subqueries
  3   use-indexes
  4   remove-filter-covered-by-index
  5   remove-unnecessary-calculations-2
  6   splice-subqueries

Query Statistics:
 Writes Exec   Writes Ign   Scan Full   Scan Index   Filtered   Peak Mem [b]   Exec Time [s]
           0            0      304000          492     302977        1441792         2.65203

Query Profile:
 Query Stage           Duration [s]
 initializing               0.00000
 parsing                    0.00006
 optimizing ast             0.00001
 loading collections        0.00001
 instantiating plan         0.00003
 optimizing plan            0.00056
 executing                  2.65136
 finalizing                 0.00003
```

Comment: Looks like the subquery produces a lot of results, most of which are filtered out by the `rlinkVal != null` condition. In order speed up the subquery you could try to create an index on `["_from", "attribute"]` for the core_edge_values_links collection, and instead of returning `re` simply return `true` (apparently you are not interested in the actual value, but only if one exists). This should allow the execution to work only with the index and avoids fetching the document from the document column family.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Returning `true` instead of `re` has a marginal effect and adding an index on `[_from, attribute]` has no effect at all. Indeed, it's not even used during execution. ArangoDB prefers using the built-in index on `_from` only

Comment: Hm, then it still needs to load the full document. Can you add an index hint to enforce usage of your new index?

Comment: Are you sure the index was already fully created at the time you tried the query?

Comment: Yep, it is fully created. According to the doc, `indexHint` is not supported on traversals

Comment: Hm... I find it strange that the optimizer did not pick the index by itself. Which version are you running? I might be able to run a few experiments in the next few days, but not today.

Comment: My last attempts are on 3.9.2. I had the same behavior on 3.7

Comment: In general you can of course perform traversals as part of a subquery, but I think in this particular case you don't even need a traversal. Can you explain what exactly you want to achieve with this query?

Comment: Thanks for your help @mpoeter ! The attribute "director" is a property of the titles. Here, I just want to know which titles have a value for the "director" attribute (and which doesn't). We're using an edge to link titles and persons mostly for other use cases, like handling multiple links more easily, adding some metadata on the link... I'll try to query edge collection directly instead of running a traversal

Comment: Ok, so you are not interested in paths with multiple edges, but really just want to know if you have an edge with attribute "directors" starting from your current title. In this case a subquery with a join should be better suited than a traversal. (And then it should also pick your newly created index.)

Comment: I just tried with a join. Execution time is pretty similar even if index is used. I edited the original question with more details on the "join" query